# In App Upgrade for Android Oreo (API Version 26)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

My App is distributed outside of Play Store and it is upgraded within the App when there is a new version available. I am using the below code to start the install (after the file was downloaded using `DownloadManager`)

```
String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/app.apk";
```

For Android N (24):

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctxt, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(destination));
Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                        
openFileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);                    
openFileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
openFileIntent.setData(contentUri);
startActivity(openFileIntent);
```

For Android 23 and below:

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
install.setDataAndType(uri,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(install);
```

When I use the same code for "Android N", it is not showing the system install activity in Android Oreo. Anyone who has solved this problem?

Comment: Have you requested [the `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES)?

Comment: Not yet, let me try with that.